# Manually scrolling a UIView contentOffset

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to scroll the contents of a **UIView** using the contentOffset which so far I achieve handling **touchesBegan**: and **touchesMoves**: methods of the view, however I get a jumpy effect as I'm changing the bounds of the UIView manually (for example: current position +/- the change of the last position of the finger and the new position)

Is there any easy way to achieve this without manually changing the bounds of the UIView?

**IMPORTANT NOTES:** I'm not using a **UIScrollView** because the mentioned **UIView** has plenty of  **draggable subviews** so if I use a **UIScrollView** I can't drag because the **UIViewScroll** scrolling event executes over the subviews events.

Animating the layer of the mentioned UIView causes the contents to move out of control, like if the point of reference had changed somehow.

However I'm always open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather make a UIView container clipping subviews, add the content view which we will drag as a subview and change it's frame. I think it shouldn't have jumpy effect as it must be the same as animating the view frame change.

Comment: That's the implementation I have, but I while moving the bounds of the clipping view it looks jumpy. I'm trying to find a way to make the UIView bounds go from X to Y in a timely fashion so it doesn't look jumpy

Comment: I was actually using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` catching `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` state, for example you can at the following tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/ Implementing Movement method. That's not exactly the implementation i used, but it's close and I hope it will work fine.